# An elegant way to simplify the provided code

Tags: c#, string, list

Assume there is a list:

```
var rawItems = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("A", "1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("B", "2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("C", "3")
};
```

And it is needed to construct a string int the following form:

```
A = 1,
B = 2,
C = 3
```

The method being used:

```
List<string> transformedItems = new List<string>();
rawItems.ForEach(item => transformedItems.Add(item.Key + " = " + item.Value));
string result = String.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, transformedItems.ToArray());
```

I would be gladly surprised if someone could think of a more elegant way of doing this.

P.S.: Not necessarily "same code packed in one line" type of solution but rather another way.

Comment: I think it's pretty elegant the way it is.

Comment: If you want speed, use Tuple<string, string> instead.

Comment: @ThanosMarkou, there is a better way. See the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps you'll find this "elegant":

```
var result = string.Join(",\r\n", rawItems.Select(
                                  x => string.Format("{0} = {1}", x.Key, x.Value)));
```

Comment: Was looking for something like this. You rock.

Comment: AFAIK, "\r\n" = Environment.NewLine on Windows platform. Did you use it for briefness?

Comment: @Anar Yup. You can use `Environment.NewLine` if you'd like. Wanted to keep it brief.

Answer (score 2):

I usually define an extension method for Join (in a static class somewhere):

```
static string StringJoin<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, string separator)
{
    return string.Join(separator, values);
}
```

Then you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
string result =
    rawItems
        .Select(item => item.Key + " = " + item.Value)
        .StringJoin("," + Environment.NewLine);
```